# making space between next values on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is how my code for chart looks like:

```
  ggplot(dane, aes(x=państwo, y=całkowiteZarobki)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=rodzajSportu, size=całkowiteZarobki)) +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
  labs(subtitle="Area Vs Population", 
       y="Population", 
       x="Area", 
       title="Scatterplot", 
       caption = "Source: midwest")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

I have been searching how to fix this problem for several hours now sadly I failed to find solution. I am also adding how my data looks like as you suggested. Here is how it looks like:

```
Rank              Name      Sport    Total.Pay Salary.Winnings Endorsements             Nation Gender Year.of.birth
1    55     Aaron Rodgers   Football  $22,000,000     $14,500,000   $7,500,000      United States   Male          1983
2    95        Adam Scott       Golf  $17,700,000      $8,700,000   $9,000,000          Australia   Male          1980
3    60   Adrian Gonzalez   Baseball  $21,500,000     $21,100,000     $400,000      United States   Male          1982
4    48    Alex Rodriguez   Baseball  $22,900,000     $22,600,000     $300,000      United States   Male          1975
5    93   Alfonso Soriano   Baseball  $18,050,000     $18,000,000      $50,000 Dominican Republic   Male          1976
6    27 Amar'e Stoudemire Basketball  $26,700,000     $21,700,000   $5,000,000      United States   Male          1982
7    75        Barry Zito   Baseball  $20,400,000     $20,300,000     $100,000      United States   Male          1978
8    47     Blake Griffin Basketball  $23,000,000     $16,500,000   $6,500,000      United States   Male          1989
9    91    Branden Albert   Football  $18,435,000     $18,400,000      $35,000      United States   Male          1984
10   97  Brandon Marshall   Football  $17,500,000     $16,800,000     $700,000      United States   Male          1984
11   74     Carl Crawford   Baseball  $20,500,000     $20,200,000     $300,000      United States   Male          1981
12   84     Carlos Dunlap   Football  $18,750,000     $18,700,000      $50,000      United States   Male          1989
13   24   Carmelo Anthony Basketball  $29,400,000     $21,400,000   $8,000,000      United States   Male          1984
14   37       CC Sabathia   Baseball  $24,200,000     $23,000,000   $1,200,000      United States   Male          1980
15   37        Chris Paul Basketball  $24,200,000     $18,700,000   $5,500,000      United States   Male          1985
16   57        Chris Bosh Basketball  $21,800,000     $19,300,000   $2,500,000      United States   Male          1984
17   30         Cliff Lee   Baseball  $25,300,000     $25,100,000     $200,000      United States   Male          1978
18   70       Cole Hamels   Baseball  $20,700,000     $20,500,000     $200,000      United States   Male          1983
19   40    Darrelle Revis   Football  $23,800,000     $23,000,000     $800,000      United States   Male          1985
20   80       David Ortiz   Baseball  $19,800,000     $14,800,000   $5,000,000 Dominican Republic   Male          1975
21   35       Derek Jeter   Baseball  $24,300,000     $15,300,000   $9,000,000      United States   Male          1974
22   79    Deron Williams Basketball  $20,000,000     $18,500,000   $1,500,000      United States   Male          1984
23   13      Derrick Rose Basketball  $36,600,000     $17,600,000  $19,000,000      United States   Male          1988
24   45     Dirk Nowitzki Basketball  $23,200,000     $22,700,000     $500,000            Germany   Male          1978
25   33      Zack Greinke   Baseball  $24,450,000     $24,400,000      $50,000      United States   Male          1983
26   66        Drew Brees   Football  $21,000,000     $10,000,000  $11,000,000      United States   Male          1979
27   29     Dwight Howard Basketball  $25,500,000     $20,500,000   $5,000,000      United States   Male          1985
28   23       Dwyane Wade Basketball  $29,900,000     $18,900,000  $11,000,000      United States   Male          1982
29    6       Tiger Woods       Golf  $61,200,000      $6,200,000  $55,000,000      United States   Male          1975
30   66       Eli Manning   Football  $21,000,000     $13,500,000   $7,500,000      United States   Male          1981
31   11    Manny Pacquiao     Boxing  $41,800,000     $41,000,000     $800,000        Philippines   Male          1978
32   77   Felix Hernandez   Baseball  $20,300,000     $20,100,000     $200,000          Venezuela   Male          1986
33   21   Fernando Alonso     Racing  $31,000,000     $29,000,000   $2,000,000              Spain   Male          1981
34   63   Fernando Torres     Soccer  $21,300,000     $17,800,000   $3,500,000              Spain   Male          1984
35    1  Floyd Mayweather     Boxing $105,000,000    $105,000,000           $0      United States   Male          1977
36   92    Franck RibĂ©ry     Soccer  $18,300,000     $16,800,000   $1,500,000             France   Male          1983
37   14       Gareth Bale     Soccer  $36,400,000     $25,400,000  $11,000,000              Wales   Male          1989
38   53       Geno Atkins   Football  $22,350,000     $22,300,000      $50,000      United States   Male          1988
39   59       Yaya TourĂ©     Soccer  $21,700,000     $19,200,000   $2,500,000        Ivory Coast   Male          1983
40   64    Henrik Stenson       Golf  $21,200,000     $18,000,000   $3,200,000             Sweden   Male          1976
41   94       Jairus Byrd   Football  $18,000,000     $17,900,000     $100,000      United States   Male          1986
42   70      Jason Peters   Football  $20,750,000     $20,700,000      $50,000      United States   Male          1982
43   97      Jayson Werth   Baseball  $17,500,000     $17,300,000     $200,000      United States   Male          1979
44   86       Jeff Gordon     Racing  $18,700,000     $13,700,000   $5,000,000      United States   Male          1971
45   42    Jimmie Johnson     Racing  $23,500,000     $17,000,000   $6,500,000      United States   Male          1975
46   52       Joe Johnson Basketball  $22,500,000     $21,500,000   $1,000,000      United States   Male          1981
47   48     Johan Santana   Baseball  $22,900,000     $22,500,000     $400,000          Venezuela   Male          1979
48   18  Matthew Stafford   Football  $33,000,000     $31,500,000   $1,500,000      United States   Male          1988
49   77     Albert Pujols   Baseball  $20,300,000     $18,300,000   $2,000,000 Dominican Republic   Male          1980
50   32    Miguel Cabrera   Baseball  $24,600,000     $22,600,000   $2,000,000          Venezuela   Male          1983
51   31         Joe Mauer   Baseball  $24,800,000     $23,000,000   $1,800,000      United States   Male          1983
52   62         Joe Haden   Football  $21,350,000     $21,200,000     $150,000      United States   Male          1989
53   69    Julius Peppers   Football  $20,800,000     $20,400,000     $400,000      United States   Male          1980
54   70  Justin Verlander   Baseball  $20,700,000     $20,200,000     $500,000      United States   Male          1983
55   20      Kevin Durant Basketball  $31,900,000     $17,900,000  $14,000,000      United States   Male          1988
56    5       Kobe Bryant Basketball  $61,500,000     $30,500,000  $31,000,000      United States   Male          1978
57   89  Larry Fitzgerald   Football  $18,500,000     $17,000,000   $1,500,000      United States   Male          1983
58    3      LeBron James Basketball  $72,300,000     $19,300,000  $53,000,000      United States   Male          1984
59   19    Lewis Hamilton     Racing  $32,000,000     $29,000,000   $3,000,000            England   Male          1985
60   41             Li Na     Tennis  $23,600,000      $5,600,000  $18,000,000              China Female          1982
61    4      Lionel Messi     Soccer  $64,700,000     $41,700,000  $23,000,000          Argentina   Male          1987
62  100      Luis SuĂˇrez     Soccer  $17,300,000     $13,300,000   $4,000,000            Uruguay   Male          1987
```

[image: As you can see y axis looks terrible please advise me how can I make space between next positions on it to make it look clearer]

PS. Any idea why it says 100 milion dollars is the lowest value? It clearly should be on top of y axis yet it stays at the bottom.

Comment: Most probably because `Population` is character/factor variable. Convert it to numeric by removing commas, `$`, use `as.numeric` and check again.

Comment: This will also lead to fewer axis labels and thus solve your question

Comment: I have already tried that, but when I change it to numeric it changes amount of dollars to numers from 0-100. As you can tell that is not perfect since I would like to know what amount of money they earned.

Comment: It might be that it reads factor levels instead of the actual values. Try as.numeric(as.character(...)).

Comment: So I tried doing it and here is what i got:

Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised. 
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: Removed 100 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth). 
6: Removed 100 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Comment: Just so you know my csv has 100 rows so after that it pretty much deleted all of them. Now chart is compleatly empty :(

Comment: So could you please include the output of `dput(dane,20)` into your question? So we know, how your data is formatted?

Comment: The changing of the values indeed points towards a factor conversion due to perhaps having actual $-signs in the data?

Comment: Yes $ is exacly the problem and I do not know to get get rid of it. data is like this:
10$
15$
20$...
so what I am trying to do is to place less instances on y axis so its not like this but 
0$
20$
40$
60$ etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments provided by @RonakShah and @TobiO, it looks like your `całkowiteZarobki` variable is being read as character instead of number (probably because of the $ symbol and the commas). To extract only the numbers and convert them to numeric you can use the following code:

```
as.numeric(unlist(lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(dane$całkowiteZarobki,"[0-9]+"),
          function(entry) paste0(entry,collapse=""))))
```

Afterwards, you can use the ggplot code you made and add the following code to format the y axis as dollars with commas.

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)
```

Comment: Hi! I did as you told me and added the code however there is a new problem. Here is changed part of the code:
gg <- ggplot(dane, aes(x=panstwo, y=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(dane$całkowiteZarobki,"[0-9]+"), function(entry) paste0(entry,collapse="")))))) +
geom_point(aes(col=rodzajSportu, size=calkowiteZarobki)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)+...
But this warning came out: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): y

Comment: hmm sounds like the `y` is not being created as expected, so it has different length of the `x` length. First, I would try to examine if the result from the  first code I suggested contains only numbers and has the same length as `panstwo`. That would help determine where ther error is. It will also help if you include your data in the question as @TobiO suggested.

Comment: X must have different length because it is countries from which players come from and Y is suppsoed to be how much theese players won. Basically there can be several players from one country so multiple values from Y are paired with single value on X.

Comment: Ok. Then you should transform your data from wide to long format. You can use the `tidyr::gather` to do this. After performing this transformation you should have one `y` per `x` observation (each country will be repeated the same number of `y` observations). Then the code I posted should work on the new data in long format.

Comment: You could build the plot from the data you are showing. In that data you have one observation per player. You just need to do: `df$Salary<-as.numeric(unlist(lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$Salary,"[0-9]+"), function(entry) paste0(entry,collapse=""))))`. Then do the ggplot as `ggplot(df, aes(x=Nation, y=Salary)) ...`

Comment: I am thankful for all your help but sadly I am still unable to do it. Could you please tell em what am I doing wrong? When I try this: data_long <- gather(dane, zarobki, ilosc,0:calkowiteZarobki) There is an error: Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n
In addition: Warning message:
In x:y : numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used

Comment: Thank you very much! Your latest solution worked out perfectly :D